# How to create extension file and call it in View Controller in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, extension-methods, categories

I have made extension file like this :

```
import Foundation
import Swift
import UIKit

extension UIButton{
func sayHello() {
        print("Hello bro...")
    }
}
```

[image]

and Then call sayHello method in view controller like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sayHello()  
    }
```

But show this error:
[image]

I think this problem accrued because of iron importing of extension file in view controller.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You are creating instance method in extension and tring to call like class methods

Comment: Either you need to add `class` keyword before `func` or you need to change extension from `UIButton` to `UIViewController`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation is wrong. You are creating extension of UIButton and calling a method on `UIViewController`.

```
extension UIViewController {
func sayHello() {
        print("Hello bro...")
    }
}
```

If you want to create a `UIButton` extension

```
 extension UIButton {
    func sayHello() {
            print("Hello bro...")
        }
    }
```

then you will need to call it on `UIButton` like below

```
let button = UIButton()
button.sayHello()
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

use `extension UIViewController` not use `UIButton`

below code extend UIButton so

someButton.sayHello() is works

```
extension UIButton {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello bro...")
    }
}
```

if you want use in `viewDidLoad()` of UIViewController extend UIViewController instead UIButton

```
extension UIViewController {
    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello bro...")
    }
}
```

it works in 'viewDidLoad'

this is some example extension to call alert

ex)

```
extension UIViewController {
    func alert(title: String, message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.view.tintColor = .black
        let someAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Some", style: .default, handler: nil)
        //let alertController.addAction(someAction)
        alertController.addAction(someAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```